# Asp.Net Core 3.1 - No Exception Middleware added in Startup - what happens?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

1. What happens (in depth) when you dont specify an Exception Handler Middleware like UseExceptionHandler or UseDeveloperExceptionPage?
2. Why are the cors headers, set via the UseCors Middleware lost when an exception occurs?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hi @emrich, If you do not use Exception handeler middleware, it will only display browser default 500 error page.

Comment: yes and how is the http 500 returned in depth like which class is responsible for settings status code etc.?